# Help with a proof regarding almost everywhere equal functions

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to show that if $f=g$, almost everywhere on some set X, where g is lebesgue integrable, then f is also lebesgue integrable and we have

$\int_{X}fd\mu=\int_{X}gd\mu$

I have googled this an found no proof of it, but I am sure it must be easy to prove. Can anyone show me how to prove this equation?

Answer (score 1):

Let $N$ be the null set such that $\forall x \in X \setminus N (f(x)=g(x))$. Then $\int_X (f(x) - g(x)) d\mu = \int_{X \setminus N} (f(x) - g(x)) d\mu + \int_N (f(x) - g(x)) d\mu = \int_{X \setminus N} 0 d\mu + 0 =0$. Thus $\int_X (f(x) - g(x)) d\mu = 0$ and $\int_X f(x) d\mu = \int_X g(x)d\mu$ by linearity.

Comment: You didn't show that $f$ is integrable. You seem to have assumed the integral exists and then proved it's equal to the integral of $g$.

Comment: $\int_N |g|$ is always defined and it is $0$ since $N$ has measure $0$. So $\int_X |g| =\int_{X\setminus N} |g|= \int_{X\setminus N} |f| \leq \int_X |f| <\infty$.

Comment: I know that, and I'm sure Jonathan knows that, but 1) the question asker might not know that, and 2) the answer is incomplete without it.

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional assumption: the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{S}$ on $X$ is actually $\mu$-complete.  This isn't too big a concern since we could define an extension $\mu(A\triangle N)=\mu(A)$ for all $A\in\mathcal{S}$ and $N$ a subset of a $\mu$-null set.

Then we have $f$ is measurable since the the inverse image $f^{-1}(B)$ of a measurable $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ differs from $g^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{S}$ by a subset of the $\mu$-null set $(f\neq g)$, thus measurable.

Now in the approximation $g=\lim g_n$ by simple functions (e.g. taking dyadic fraction values)
$$
g_n=\sum_{j} \lambda_{j,n} 1_{A_{j,n}}
$$
define the analogous
$$
f_n=\sum_{j} \lambda_{j,n} 1_{A_{j,n}\triangle N_{j,n}}
$$
where $N_{j,n}$ is a subset of $(f\neq g)$.
Then you have $f_n\to f$ if you chose $N_{j,n}$ appropriately (exercise), and $\int f_n\,\mathrm{d}\mu = \int g_n\,\mathrm{d}\mu$, so taking limit we are done.

Comment: The question specifically asks about Lesbesgue measure, which is complete. We do not need that as an additional assumption.

Comment: I disagree with the statement that "we typically use" the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. I'm a Banach space theorist, and I'd argue that unless otherwise stated, Lebesgue measure is on the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra.

In any case, I think it is clear from the wording of the question that the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra is the one which is being asked about.